# While protecting the app with OAuth2, I'd like to expose some URLs accessible to anyone

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

After I created a small *Spring Boot 2.2.6* application and I configured *AWS Cognito* as authentication provider, everything work well. When accessing any of application's URLs, I am redirected to Cognito and, after login, the application worked well.

I try to add some public pages (/api/**), which do not require any authentication. 
First I tried this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();  // This should be permitted for anyone
```

but, now, everything is open. No security at all. Ooops.

I change it to:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()  // This should be permitted for anyone
                .anyRequest().authenticated();       // Everything else should be protected
```

Now, the whitelisted URL (/api/**) work well, no password. But all other URL (eg. /private), instead of redirecting me to the login page, produce a 403 error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Access Denied

Does anybody have any idea how to keep the original behaviour (password) but with few URLs accessible anonymously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has another method that can be used to ignore certain urls:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/**");
}
```